# TypeError: 'ListNode' object is not iterable in K Reverse Linked List question

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I am practising Linked List questions on InterviewBit. The question here is
'Given a singly linked list and an integer K, reverse the nodes of the
list K at a time and returns modified linked list.

NOTE : The length of the list is divisible by K'

Following a naive approach, this is what I do:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#   def __init__(self, x):
#       self.val = x
#       self.next = None

class Solution:
    def reversesubList(self, A, B):
        prev = None 
        cur = A
        if cur.next is None:
            return A 

        count = 0 
        while(cur is not None) and count<B:
            nxt = cur.next 
            cur.next = prev 
            prev = cur 
            cur = nxt 
            count += 1

        self.head = prev 
        return self.head, cur
    # @param A : head node of linked list
    # @param B : integer
    # @return the head node in the linked list
    def reverseList(self, A, B):
        current = A
        last_of_prev = None 
        count = 0
        while current is not None:
            reversed_head, new_head = self.reversesubList(current, B)
            # print(reversed_head.val)
            # print(new_head.val)
            if count>0: 
                last_of_prev.next = reversed_head
            else: 
                start = reversed_head
                last_of_prev = current
            current.next = new_head
            current = new_head
            count += 1  
       return start
```

The idea is to traverse the list and by switching the pointers for each set of B elements considered at a time, in one pass we should be able to do the question. I get the following error though and am unable to pinpoint why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 228, in <module>
    Z = obj.reverseList(A, B)
  File "/tmp/judge/solution.py", line 25, in reverseList
    reversed_head, new_head = self.reversesubList(current, B)
TypeError: 'ListNode' object is not iterable
```

Any help that can make me understand the error would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `reversesubList()` returns a single `ListNode` but your calling code expects two values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are these issues:

- `reversesubList` has both `return A` (one value) and `return self.head, cur` (tuple). This is inconsistent. Where you call this function, you expect a tuple, so the first `return` is wrong. Actually that `if` block where it occurs, can just be removed
- The indentation of `return start` is off by one space (maybe a typo in the question only)
- The assignment `last_of_prev = current` should not only happen in the `else` case, but *always*. So move it out of the `else` body.

Not issues, but the following things could be improved:

- The `count` variable seems overkill as it is only used to see if it was the first iteration of the loop or not. For this you can use `if last_of_prev` -- so there is no need for the `count` variable.
- In `reversesubList` there should be no need to assign to `self.head` -- it is never read. Just do `return prev, nxt` without that assignment.
- `current.next = new_head` is not really needed, because the (remainder) list that starts at `new_head` still needs to be reversed in the next iteration of the loop, so there this assignment will need to be anyway corrected, which happens with the assignment (in the next iteration) to `last_of_prev.next`.
- Even if the template code might have suggested variables `A` and `B`, it is better to use more descriptive variables, like `head` and `count`. And then in the `reversesubList` function you can decrement the given `count` without the need for another variable.

Taking all that together we get this:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x, nxt=None):
        self.val = x
        self.next = nxt

    # Some helper methods to be able to test outside
    #    the code-challenge site's framework
    @classmethod
    def of(Cls, values):
        head = None
        for value in reversed(values):
            head = Cls(value, head)
        return head

    def __iter__(self):
        head = self
        while head:
            yield head.val
            head = head.next

class Solution:
    def reversesubList(self, head, count):
        prev = None 
        cur = head

        while cur is not None and count > 0:
            nxt = cur.next 
            cur.next = prev 
            prev = cur 
            cur = nxt 
            count -= 1

        return prev, cur

    def reverseList(self, head, count):
        current = head
        last_of_prev = None 
        start = None
        while current is not None:
            reversed_head, new_head = self.reversesubList(current, count)
            if last_of_prev: 
                last_of_prev.next = reversed_head
            else: 
                start = reversed_head
            last_of_prev = current
            current = new_head
        return start

# Test
lst = ListNode.of([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(*lst)

lst = Solution().reverseList(lst, 3)
print(*lst)
```

Comment: This has been super helpful and elaborate, thank you! 
Sorry for not getting back earlier.